# Flutter; I want my app to get a list of all the installed apps with their names, icon and the storage they are using

Tags: android, flutter

Recommend the best package for it and also the required user permission for it.

I am currently using installed_apps package but I am confused about which user permission is required to use this package. Can somebody give me some pointers about this situation?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the permission QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES.

To access the required permission QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES, ensure that you explicitly request it.

Take caution when dealing with the Play Store; you must provide a detailed explanation of why your app requires this permission. Additionally, when prompting users within the app for this permission, include a disclosure that clearly outlines the specific reasons behind the need for the permission.

For more information, refer to the following [link](https://helpcenter.appsealing.com/hc/en-us/articles/6310295171225-How-to-submit-QUERY-ALL-PACKAGES-permission-usage-form-at-Google-Play-Console):